# XPath: select element with specific child and not another specific child

Tags: xml, xpath, openstreetmap

It appears that, nowadays, always tagging Openstreetmap nodes with a source is a bad habit - the source tag should only be specified when the source is particular and differs from the source tagged to the changeset. It is especially not welcome when the node has no other tag. It was not always that way - there was a time when changeset tagging was not a standard practice. So in some places where I have heavily edited, I have some clean up to do and I intend to build myself a tool for that.

Let's for example start with this sample data set:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version='0.6' upload='true' generator='JOSM'>
<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
</node>
<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="power" v="tower" />
</node>
<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
  <tag k="power" v="tower" />
</node>
</osm>
```

First I want to select all Openstreetmap nodes that contain `<tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />` - very easy using

```
/osm/node/tag[@v = "Microsoft Bing orbital imagery"]/..
```

Result, as expected:

```
Element='<node id="3736237027" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771207" lon="-16.3332326">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
</node>'
Element='<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
  <tag k="power" v="tower" />
</node>'
```

But the second element also has a `<tag k="power" v="tower" />` and I do not want to select nodes with any tag but a source tag. So I try

```
/osm/node/tag[@v = "Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" and ../tag[not(@k != "source")]]/..
```

Result: this gets me the exact same result as above. There must be something I don't understand about operator precedence in xpath.

Just to check, I try

```
/osm/node/tag[not(@k = "source")]/..
```

Result, as expected:

```
Element='<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="power" v="tower" />
</node>'
Element='<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
  <tag k="power" v="tower" />
</node>'
```

Experimenting further I tried to combine expressions into

```
/osm/node/tag[@v = "Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" and ../tag[@k = "power"]]/..
```

Result, as expected:

```
Element='<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
  <tag k="power" v="tower" />
</node>'
```

Very well... So the following should work:

```
/osm/node/tag[@v = "Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" and ../tag[not(@k = "power")]]/..
```

Result, not what I expected:

```
Element='<node id="3736237027" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771207" lon="-16.3332326">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
</node>'
Element='<node id="3736237028" timestamp="2015-09-09T15:27:34Z" uid="160042" user="Jean-Marc Liotier" visible="true" version="1" changeset="33912319" lat="15.4771238" lon="-16.3349496">
  <tag k="source" v="Microsoft Bing orbital imagery" />
  <tag k="power" v="tower" />
</node>'
```

Am I misunderstanding the way not() works ?

By the way, all this testing has been performed using http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html - I don't know if it is the right tool for testing XPath.

Is the sort of multiple combined conditions I am attempting implementable as a single XPath expression or is it going to require a two step process, first selecting the elements that have the tag attribute I require and then excluding the ones I don't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first XPath might be written more simply as

```
/osm/node[tag/@v = "Microsoft Bing orbital imagery"]
```

You can then add the second condition which says "and there's no tag other than source":

```
/osm/node[tag/@v = "Microsoft Bing orbital imagery"
          and not(tag/@k != 'source')]
```

The problem was not precedence, but scope. You wanted to negate `tag`, not its attributes. Your last XPath tried to search for a tag whose sibling-or-self `tag` has @k different to "power".

Comment: I thought that by putting the two conditions inside the brackets of the same element they would apply contradictorily to the same instance of that element in the original document... So with that wrong assumption I did not attempt this approach. Thank you for your sharp answer - I'm increasingly excited at how powerful XPath is, especially compared to the hackish text pattern matching I come from...